# React interaction between components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component which looks like the following

**UploadView.js**

```
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            file: null,
            mappingType: null
        }
    },

    setMappingType: function(){
        this.setState({
            mappingType: this.state.mappingType
        });
    },

    render: function(){
       <FileDropdown mappingType={this.setMappingType}/>
       <FileUpload mappingType={this.state.mappingType}/>
    }
```

FileDropDown is a child component that presents the user with a dropdown feature and looks as the following

**FileDropDown.js**

```
    pickedOption: function(event){
        var option = event.nativeEvent.target.selectedIndex;
        var value = event.nativeEvent.target[option].text;
        this.props.mappingType = value;
    },

    render: function(){
        return (
          <select name="typeoptions" id="mappingTypes" onChange={this.pickedOption}>.....</select>
        )
    }
```

I am trying to understand, if the above the right way to update the state and will updating/setting the value **this.props.mappinType** in FileDropDown will set the updated value to the state **mappingType** in the parent UploadView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you send a function (or method) called *setMappingType* from **UploadView.js** to **FileDropDown.js**. When picking an option in **FileDropDown.js** at the method *pickedOption* you will call this function, causing the parent component to update.

Instead of doing that, you actually assigned the value to the props. In other words, change this

```
this.props.mappingType = value;
```

into

```
this.props.mappingType(value);
```

Then change the method *setMappingType* to a function which actually receives this value

```
setMappingType: function(value){
    this.setState({
        mappingType: value
    });
},
```

---

Oh and something else, unrelated to your question, you can retrieve your value using refs like so:

```
pickedOption: function(event){
    var value = this.refs._myRef.value;
},

render: function(){
    return (
      <select ref='_myRef' onChange={this.pickedOption}>
        <option value='1'>One</option>
        <option value='2'>Two</option>
      </select>
    )
}
```

I hope it helps ;)

Comment: Thanks @Prutser, for the additional tip

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, no, it won't work this way.
You need to change your setMappingType function to:

```
setMappingType: function(value){
    this.setState({
        mappingType: value
    });
},
```

As you currently have it, it will just always be set to null because you are setting the state variable mappingType to the value of the state variable mappingType which is initially null. So it will just stay that way.

The proper way to pass the value to the parent function is like this:

```
pickedOption: function(event){
    var option = event.nativeEvent.target.selectedIndex;
    var value = event.nativeEvent.target[option].text;
    this.props.mappingType(value);
},
```

Assigning it as you have, won't work.
I''ll admit I'm not an expert in React, but to my understanding this is how things need to be done. Hope this helps.